# JAXB Unmarshaling - Lists

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am currently working on a project for selfuse and got some problems with understanding the unmarshaling process in JAXB.

I've got my Objects, which i want to save into an XML File, what i do with marshalling. Now i need the Objects, which i load with unmarshaling, in an ArrayList, so i can look through all of them, while i am searching for certain things.

My code looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    private String telephone;
    private String firm = null;

// getters and Setters and Constructor
....
 }
```

And My JAXB Unmarshaller:

```
public void loadCustomers() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
}
```

Where do i set in, in Order to insert the created Objects into a list?
Would it be possible to do something like

```
ArrayList customerList = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Or is there only the way with creating Sub and Superclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Question ain't that special and i didnt do my research properly.

This [Link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jaxb/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/) did it for me. It's explained very well and just what i needed.